# How to split a kml file

Tags: qgis, kml

I have a county KML file, and it works under QGIS, but I need to split the file according to a data field.  How do I do this?

an example county within the file is below:

```
<Folder>
<open>0</open>
<name>TN_Houston</name>
<Placemark>
<visibility>1</visibility>
<styleUrl>#USCounties</styleUrl>
<MultiGeometry>
<LineString>
<coordinates>
-87.5135193,36.3346596,0 -87.5236130,36.2488365,0 -87.5314636,36.2496452,0 -87.5304031,36.2323189,0 -87.5665894,36.1778755,0 -87.5722122,36.1787834,0 -87.5737915,36.1821823,0 -87.5783463,36.1830215,0 -87.5765457,36.1892662,0 -87.5866699,36.1927223,0 -87.5859604,36.1976433,0 -87.6621780,36.2011719,0 -87.6871872,36.2174225,0 -87.7073898,36.2271118,0 -87.7311096,36.2354279,0 -87.7579727,36.2414665,0 -87.7984848,36.2447014,0 -87.8353958,36.2323036,0 -87.9495773,36.2431030,0 -87.9442673,36.2641182,0 -87.9476166,36.2852516,0 -87.9571533,36.3149757,0 -87.9617233,36.3226204,0 -87.9686203,36.3271790,0 -87.9706497,36.3385658,0 -87.9811859,36.3537102,0 -87.9500046,36.3523712,0 -87.9449615,36.3540916,0 -87.9264908,36.3449669,0 -87.8928146,36.3346596,0 -87.8615417,36.3298187,0 -87.8217926,36.3286705,0 -87.7844162,36.3340721,0 -87.7562637,36.3429108,0 -87.7227859,36.3603096,0 -87.7154694,36.3681870,0 -87.5923462,36.3676109,0 -87.5869598,36.3417320,0 -87.5135193,36.3346596,0 
</coordinates>
</LineString>
</MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
</Folder>
<Folder>
```

In `<name>TN_Houston</name>`  I need to break the KML based on the first two characters.   The result is multiple files each based on those two first characters.  For example a TN.kml that would include the above polygon and all other `TN_*` polygons.

Here is a link to the [file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z0ufczir7zs9py0/cnt_us.kml?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z0ufczir7zs9py0/cnt_us.kml?dl=0)

Comment: Could you upload the file you are trying to split somwhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS you can split the KML. Click Vector > Data Management Tools > Split Vector layer. Choose the field and then the output folder. This will not require you to change the file type.

Comment: The solution is not working with QGIS 3.16. The instruction runs, but it produces no split layers.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your KML file including its attributes to a shapefile and then use Split tool in ArcMap to split it manually.

You could also use the below link which is an extension to ArcMap to split the shapefile:

http://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/split_by_attribute_tool.html

Comment: The question asked for a way to split KML in QGIS, and you're offering an ArcGIS script for shapefiles?

Comment: It could also be done in qgis. Load kml, save as Shapefile, split, export as kml

Answer (score 1):

Attention! QGIS:  Click Vector > Data Management Tools > Split Vector layer, split KML into several shapefiles, not into several KML files.